# How do I take a string and order its letters

Tags: php, string

If I have a string `flags`, how do I make sure that its letters are ordered alphabetically, in this case `afgls`?

Comment: There's also [`count_chars(…, 3)`](http://php.net/count_chars) if you want only the unique characters (or don't care about repeated ones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split), [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort), and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$arr = str_split($str)
sort($arr, SORT_STRING);
$str = implode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to use string split function instead of explode

You will likely want to use the str_split function: http://us.php.net/str_split

As well as the Array Sort function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

And finally, the Implode function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Ah - you're right. the str_split is the better option. Though - i don't think the slight discrepancy was worth a down-vote :\

Comment: The down vote wasn't from Tim ;) It's because you gave references but no working solution, which was a little too much for a simple question like this.

Comment: Didn't say it was. And - down voting people because they don't spoon feed you the answer isn't what the button is for. I felt that manual references were sufficient, and that it wasn't asking too much for you to read how the functions work.